# Working around non-scaling-stroke bug in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

A recent Chrome release (not sure exact version) has broken some of my SVG such that `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke` renders badly-aliased polylines. I cannot figure out what is triggering the bug.

```js
var viewBoxen = {
  good:"-55.91646158020719 -61.478141667102406 111.83292317296 122.95628333555779",
  bad:"-55.92 -61.48 111.83 122.96"
};
var svg  = document.querySelector('svg'),
    span = document.querySelector('span');
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i=buttons.length;i--;) (function(btn){
  var viewBox = viewBoxen[btn.id];
  btn.onclick = function(){
    span.innerHTML = viewBox;
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox',viewBox);
  }
})(buttons[i]);
buttons[1].click();
```

```css
svg { display:inline-block; width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid red; margin:10px }
polyline { fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-55.92 -61.48 111.83 122.96">
  <polyline points="19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 -0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 -0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 -0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,-0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37 22.07,48.69 41.77,52.17 38.99,32.36 19.58,37.20 22.36,57.01 42.06,60.48 54.92,45.16 52.13,25.35 38.24,10.97 19.70,3.47 0.00,-0.00 -19.70,-3.47 -38.24,-10.97 -52.13,-25.35 -54.92,-45.16 -42.06,-60.48 -22.36,-57.01 -19.58,-37.20 -38.99,-32.36 -41.77,-52.17 -22.07,-48.69 -34.93,-33.37 -37.71,-53.18 -23.82,-38.79 -42.36,-46.28 -22.67,-42.81 -42.36,-46.28 -23.82,-38.79 -37.71,-53.18 -34.93,-33.37 -22.07,-48.69 -41.77,-52.17 -38.99,-32.36 -19.58,-37.20 -22.36,-57.01 -42.06,-60.48 -54.92,-45.16 -52.13,-25.35 -38.24,-10.97 -19.70,-3.47 0.00,0.00 19.70,3.47 38.24,10.97 52.13,25.35 54.92,45.16 42.06,60.48 22.36,57.01 19.58,37.20 38.99,32.36 41.77,52.17 22.07,48.69 34.93,33.37 37.71,53.18 23.82,38.79 42.36,46.28 22.67,42.81 42.36,46.28 23.82,38.79 37.71,53.18 34.93,33.37"/>
  <polyline points="-55.92,-61.48 55.92,61.48"/>
</svg>

<p>viewBox="<span></span>"</p>
<p>
  <button id="good">High Precision viewBox</button>
  <button id="bad">Low Precision viewBox</button>
  </p>
```

A further example/comparison can be seen at either:

- https://jsfiddle.net/9fz59ekf/
- http://phrogz.net/SVG/TurtleTest-ChromeProblem.html

As you can see if you Run the snippet here on Stack Overflow, using a high precision for the viewBox (14 decimal places) renders the polyline as expected, but when I drop the precision (2 decimal places) the rendering of the polylines differs and gets large and aliased.

If you look at the comparisons on either JSFiddle or my web site, you can see that a high precision viewBox does not always fix the problem.

[image]

**My question**: can you help me isolate what is triggering this bug in Chrome, and (especially) figure out how to avoid it/work around it consistently?

---

<sub>Those wondering about the source of these images may be interested in http://phrogz.net/SVG/TurtleTest.html and http://phrogz.net/tmp/StarryTurtles.html</sub>

Comment: FWIW, I have filed this as a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=620861

Comment: Sorry about that. In scanning the question for code the auto collapsed snippet looked like a link.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for re-opening, and your admin vigilance.